# pg_restore is not working - input file does not appear to be a valid archive

Tags: postgresql, psql, restore, dump, pg-restore

I am doing pg_dump using -

```
pg_dump -U <username> -h <host> <database> > backup.sql
```

pg_dump is working fine.
I am trying to do pg_restore doing -

```
pg_restore -U <username> -h <host> -d <databse> backup.sql
```

Then it is showing **pg_restore: error: input file does not appear to be a valid archive**

I have checked many StackOverflow answers about this, but I could not figure out anything. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Update : As per comments we can not use pg_restore for .sql files. Actually I have an restriction that I must have to restore the database using pg_restore command. Can you please give the pg_dump command using which I can restore that using pg_restore?

Comment: You created a SQL script. You need to run that using `psql`, e.g. `psql -U username -h host -f backup.sql`

Comment: Actually I have an restriction that I must have to restore the database using pg_restore command. Can you please give the pg_dump command using which I can restore that using pg_restore? Thanks in advance

Comment: What can **we** do about the bizarre restrictions some knowledge-free person has imposed on you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created a plain format dump, which is an SQL file. You have to restore plain-format dumps with `psql`:

```bash
psql -U <username> -h <host> -d <databse> -f backup.sql
```

`pg_restore` is used to restore dumps in all other formats. You get dumps in other formats by using the appropriate `-F` option with `pg_dump`: for example, `-F c`  produces a custom format dump.

If you want to restore a plain format dump with a client other than `psql`, you have to create it with the option `--inserts`.

Comment: Actually I have an restriction that I must have to restore the database using pg_restore command. Can you please give the pg_dump command using which I can restore that using pg_restore? Thanks in advance

Comment: I have done that.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe How do you restore a dump that was created without `-F`, but with compression (i.e., `-Z9`)?

Comment: @PawelVeselov That seems unrelated to the question. The PostgreSQL documentation describes that in detail.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was outputting pg_dump with nohup because it was time-consuming, which confused the redirector and mixed unnecessary data in the file, causing the error (pg_restore: error: input file does not appear to be a valid archive).

nohup pg_dump *** > output.dump > nohup.out &

pg_dump: DEBUG: rehashing catalog cache id 41 for pg_partitioned_table; 65 tups, 32 buckets
pg_dump: DEBUG: rehashing catalog cache id 41 for pg_partitioned_table; 129 tups, 64 buckets
pg_dump: DEBUG: rehashing catalog cache id 41 for pg_partitioned_table; 257 tups, 128 buckets
pg_dump: DEBUG: rehashing catalog cache id 59 for pg_statistic; 257 tups, 128 buckets
pg_dump: DEBUG: rehashing catalog cache id 14 for pg_opclass; 17 tups, 8 buckets